# jquery: add settime function

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout

I found the code by Mary Lou http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery
I try to add the animation automatically after 5 seconds. Unfortunately, to no avail.

Can I ask for help, and adding these lines. I am not a programmer and do not really know what else I can odd tricks.

```
$(function() {
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
            }, 1000);
            event.preventDefault();
            });
       });
```

THX
dede

Answer (score 1):

The `1000` within the `animate` sets the animation duration, so if you want to wait BEFORE the animation stars, you should use: `delay(5000)` like this:

```
$(function() { 
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){ 
                var $anchor = $(this); 
                    $('html, body').stop().delay(5000).animate({ 
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left 
            }, 1000);
            event.preventDefault(); 
            }); 
       });
```

If `delay` doesn't work, try to write `idle` instead of delay.

If you want the animation to work when clicking OR 5 seconds rihgt after the page is loaded, you should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){ 
           var $anchor = $(this); 
           $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left 
           }, 1000);
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }); 
       var $anchor = $('ul.nav a');
       $('html, body').stop().delay(5000).animate({ 
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left 
       }, 1000);
       event.preventDefault(); 

});
```

Hope this is helpful !

Comment: I think it's wrong. After trying your change, it appears that when you click the animation starts after 1 second. And I want the animation to work independently of clicks. The image has to move automatically after 5 seconds or click.

Sorry for my English - written by Google Translate

Comment: My English is mostly by Google Translate too... You wrote your code within `$(document).ready(function () {.......}` ? everything written in there - applies right after the document is loaded. (Regardless of clicks).

Comment: It almost works. here is a demo - http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/. right now it moves only when clicked and I want it to move automatically after 5 seconds. And when you get to the final slide it's supposed to go back to the beginning and repeat animation.